# s3cmd ImportError: No module named S3.Exceptions

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, s3cmd

Received an error after installing and trying to run [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) 1.0.0

```
s3cmd -h

Problem: ImportError: No module named S3.Exceptions
S3cmd:   unknown version. Module import problem?

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/s3cmd", line 1995, in <module>
    from S3.Exceptions import *
ImportError: No module named S3.Exceptions

Your sys.path contains these entries:
```

This error came about after upgrading to the latest Amazon Linux distro 2015.03.0

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Looks like the error happened because python2.7 is now the default python version in the Amazon Linux 2015.03.0+  If you change python back to 2.6 and run s3cmd it should work without a problem

```
update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python2.6
s3cmd -h
```

After the s3cmd command is ran you can put python back to 2.7 for yum and other utilities:

```
update-alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python2.7
yum install <package>
```

Comment: If we are reverting the python back to 2.7, then its again starts throwing the same error, so I think its better to leave it with 2.6

Answer (score 11):

```
vi /usr/bin/s3cmd
```

add 2.6 to the first line, so it looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.6
```

Save thefile and s3cmd will work. as long as you have /usr/bin/python2.6 on your system

Comment: much better answer

Answer (score 11):

I faced a similar error with s3cmd, but module name was different:
`ImportError: No module named S3.ExitCodes`

In my case I could solve the problem this way:
`yum install python-pip` and then `pip install s3cmd`.
After that s3cmd worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the previous answers worked for me, but copying a few lines from the [sourcegraph aws-cli dockerfile](https://github.com/sourcegraph/docker-awscli/blob/master/Dockerfile) did:

FROM python:2
RUN apt-get update -q
RUN apt-get install -qy python-pip groff-base
RUN pip install awscli

Answer (score 0):

s3cmd was working with one version of my python in sys.path, it was keeping up some other version.

> sudo vi /usr/bin/s3cmd

You will see this in starting lines.

```
import sys
```

I had two python version python3.5 and python3.6

 Lets run python3.5 and then python3.6

```
import sys
print('\n'.join(sys.path))
```

Match your sys path with s3cmd error sys path. This will give you assurance that you need to change the python version in sys path for that. 

Now: **How to Change sys.path python version?**

```
echo $PYTHONPATH
sudo vi ~/.bashrc
export PYTHONPATH=/usr/bin/python3.6
```

[PYTHONPATH Help Link](https://bic-berkeley.github.io/psych-214-fall-2016/using_pythonpath.html)